# how to get value of html Input text placed inside ListView in asp.net C# code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I am having List view with Input Text box

If I am using asp TextBox and trying following Code while ItemUpdating, i am getting the value

```
obj.FName = (ObjView.Items[e.ItemIndex].FindControl("txtFName") as TextBox).Text;
```

how I have replace asp text box with html input text in aspx page, after which I am not getting the value

Comment: How did you replace? Please post original markup with textbox and new one with input.

Comment: Why would you change from asp TextBox to input=text? If you do you run into issues you describe. Also putting a normal input=text into a ListView will result in duplicate name and id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get html input value in the code-behind, first take input as follows:

```
<input type="text" runat="server" id="Details" value= '<%# Eval("Details") %>' />
```

Then in the code-behind, use the following:

```
string details = ((HtmlInputText)row.FindControl("Details")).Value;
```

By the way, without controls, you can use the following for html inputs:

```
string details = Request.Form["Details"];
```

In that case, you should add a name attribute with the name **Details**.

Answer (score 0):

To access any html input in your code behind, you must add **runat="server"** attribute for the control. Like below.

```
<input type="text" name="txtFName" id="txtFName" runat="server" />
```